# Excel - Formula - Get n values from resulting array of INDEX

Tags: excel, excel-formula

With this table named `jobSearches`:
[image: Table jobSearches]

I am able to calculate the Average of the first row using following formula:

```
=AVERAGE(INDEX(jobsearches,1,))
```

Note that `INDEX(jobsearches,1,)` returns an array of values:

[image: Array of values]

**Question:**
Is it possible to calculate the AVERAGE for *just the first n values* of the resolved array, and not for the whole row?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do something like this:

```
=AVERAGE(INDEX(jobsearches,1,2):INDEX(jobsearches,1,11))
```

Which will return the average of the first 10 numbers on the first row.

Answer (score 2):

That's exactly `OFFSET(reference,rows,cols,height,width)` function is for:

```
=AVERAGE(OFFSET(jobsearches,0,1,1,10))
```

Comment: Just for some information. Offset is a volatile function Will re calculate every time Excel recalculates. The index function only re calculates when the data changes.

Comment: @Scott Craner: Interesting... It is, indeed.
So, `OFFSET()` is as bas as `INDIRECT()`.
Thanks, that's good to know.

[What has happened before will happen again](https://trumpexcel.com/excel-volatile-formulas/)